# GTM Trigger a Tag when a field's value changes

Tags: google-tag-manager

On my site, I need to have the "Add to Cart" tag fire after a hidden field has been populated with data. How do I set up a trigger to get this to work? I have tried a variety of things and am not sure what I'm missing.

Variable to get field value:

[image: Variable configuration]

Tag to add product SKU to field when "Add" button is pushed:
This exists on page load.

[image: Add product SKU to field]

Tag that should fire after the "Add" button is pushed AND the field is populated with the new SKU.
[image: Add to Cart tag]